# Vue.jsの再コンパイルがしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, vue.js

ruby on railsのアプリケーションはViewがVue.jsで作成されています。
いくつかViewの変更が必要になったので、変更した後、サーバーを再起動しましたが、変更が反映されていません。
いろいろ調べていくと、Vue.jsはプリコンパイルされているらしいのです。
なので、Vue.jsを再コンパイルしたいと思います。
どうすれば、再コンパイルできるでしょうか。

環境は次のとおりです。
OS:utunbu16.04
ruby:2.4.2
rails:5.1
Vue.js:不明

Answer (score 2):

単にRailsアプリのフロントアセットのコンパイルと言ってもどのような構成になっているか(ビルド環境、使用技術)によって様々な場合が存在するかと思います。

Rails標準のアセットパイプラインの `sprockets-rails` や `webpacker` などを利用しているアプリケーションであれば一般的に

```
rails assets:precompile
```

でプリコンパイルが行えるでしょう。

Comment: yarnを使用していることがわかりました。この場合は、yarnを再実行しないといけませんか。

Comment: yarnはあくまでもパッケージマネージャです。もしWebpackerを使っているのであればデフォルトではassets:precompile実行時に自動で`yarn`も走りますし、もし[それが無効化されてる](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#yarn-integrity)のであればパッケージの整合性を取るためにyarnを実行する必要があるかもしれませんが、それは毎回ではありません。他方でyarnはタスクランナーとしても機能します。 `yarn run` を実行すると`package.json`に設定されたタスクの一覧が表示されますので確認してみてください。